# How to check role in yii

Tags: yii

I created a webapp with YII framework. I used rights module. And I created 3 roles. They are

1. Creator
2. Reviewer
3. Director

"Creator" has some actions and "Reviewer" has some actions. And "Director" is a child of "Creator" and "Reviewer".

The question is, if I check a role (e.g Creator), it will allow it's child role (e.g "Director").

For example, if I check "Creator" role as follow, the statement must also work for "Director" role.

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Creator'))
{
  statement....;
}
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For example:

```
$role = Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app() -> user -> Id);
            foreach ($role as $role)
                $role -> name;
            if ($role -> name == 'Creator'|| $role -> name == 'Director')
               //do what you need
```

checkAccess() checks access for item not role. For example:

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Creator'))
```

Checks acces to AuthItem 'Creator' for current role. Returns true/false.

Another example of usage - main menu for different roles:

```
$role = Rights::getAssignedRoles(Yii::app() -> user -> Id);
            foreach ($role as $role)
                $role->name;
            if ($role->name == 'Manager' or Yii::app()->user->isSuperuser) {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->clientsUrl, 'label' => "Clients", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('clients')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->providersUrl, 'label' => "Data Providers", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('providers')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->ordersUrl, 'label' => "Orders", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('orders')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label' => "Tools", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('tools')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest)),));
            } elseif ($role->name == 'Client') {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/user/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => array('/user/client/lists'), 'label' => 'Lists', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Client.Lists')), array('url' => array('/user/orders/index', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Orders', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkaccess('User.Orders.Index')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->profileUrl, 'label' => "Profile", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('tools')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest))));
            }
            ;
            if ($role->name == 'Provider') {
                $this->widget('ext.cssmenu.CssMenu', array('items' => array(array('url' => array('/user/general/index'), 'label' => "General", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('general')), array('url' => array('/user/data'), 'label' => "Data", 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('data')), array('url' => array('/user/provider/data', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Data', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => array('/user/feeds/feeds', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Feeds', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => array('/user/payments', "id" => Yii::app()->user->Id), 'label' => 'Payments', 'visible' => Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('User.Feeds.Feeds')), array('url' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->logoutUrl, 'label' => Yii::app()->getModule('user')->t("Logout"), 'visible' => !Yii::app()->user->isGuest))));
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Director has the rights of creator and reviewer

```
if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Creator'))
{
  // creator and director are here
}

if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Reviewer'))
{
  // reviewer and director are here
}

if(Yii::app()->user->checkAccess('Director'))
{
  // director is here
}
```